# Wireguard vs. OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, wireguard

Which is better in what scenario?

What cons and pros do they have? (optional question)

Which is more secure? (optional question)

Best use case of each one?

Isn't WireGuard based on OpenVPN?

Comment: This question is too broad. And it looks like that no previous research was done since there are [lots of information about this topic on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=wireguard+vs+openvpn).

Comment: I only found a forum post on golem.de and that's it

Comment: I have no idea what kind of information you exactly expected to find but there are lots of information about this topic - just follow the google search from my previous comment.

Comment: Well ok this one for example is quite good but it does not answer all of my questions (namely best use case and is WireGuard based on OpenVPN) https://www.vpnranks.com/blog/wireguard-vs-openvpn/

Comment: Where you expecting all your questions answered in a single post?

Comment: @schroeder yes, is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WireGuard is not based on OpenVPN. It is a completely new and lean VPN protocol.
The WireGuard protocol is still work in progress.

Team of Mr Jason A. Donenfeld is still working toward a stable 1.0 release. 
This means it is ready for testing purposes.

You can find much more about the WireGuard over the Internet. Please see some links provided in the question comments and some I added below.

[Donenfeld, J.A., 2017, March. WireGuard: Next Generation Kernel Network Tunnel. In NDSS.](https://www.wireguard.com/papers/wireguard.pdf)

[Official Git repositories](https://git.zx2c4.com/?q=wireguard)

[WireGuard website](https://www.wireguard.com)